# When I select Lahore, Pakistan in google autocomplete; it should pick automatically 'Lahore' only for like query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In Model

```
function get_search_fuel_prices($fuel_city){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('fuel_price');
        $this->db->like('fuel_city',$fuel_city);
        return $this->db->get()->result();

    }
```

Comment: What is the actual value of `$fuel_city` inside the function? `var_dump($fuel_city);` should tell you what actually is being passed. _Note:_ there is also a very dirty way of seeing `$fuel_city` value: `error_log($fuel_city);` will output it to error log, however it doest work for `arrays`, `objects` and even has issues when outputting `bool` values

Comment: This is the name of the city in which I am getting the values

Comment: You have to check what this variable actually contains before you do the DB quering. It is part of debugging the problem. I am not Yoda, I can't actually use the force and write the `error_log($fuel_city);` and check your apache error log, to see the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
//split the location by comma
$arr = explode(",",$fuel_city);

//then
$this->db->like('fuel_city',$arr[0]);
```